# For which value of $r$ is the nonlinear dynamical system dissipative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, hamilton-equations

I could really use some help with the following:

When I have input $u$ and output $y$ of the following nonlinear dynamical system, How can I determine for which values of $r$ this system will be dissipative? And how to represent this in port-Hamiltonian form for the values of $r$?

$\ddot{q}+r\dot{q}-\dot{q}\cos(q)+\sin(q)=u$

$y=\dot{q}$

where $r  \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar-valued parameter

Some extra info: The non linear system $\dot{x}=f(x,u), y=g(x,u)$ with input $u(t) \in\mathbb{R^p}$ and output$y(t) \in\mathbb{R^p}$ is dissipative if there exists a storage funtion $H: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that the dissipation inequality $H (x(t_1)) \leq H(x(t_0)) + \int_{t_0}^{t_1} y(t) u(t)dt$

> Can I do something like this:
>
> $x_1=q$
>
> $x_2= \dot{q}$
>
> $\dot{x_1}=x_2$ and $ \dot{x_2}+rx_2-x_2\cos(x_1)+\sin(x_1)=u$
>
> $\begin{pmatrix}
>  \dot{x_1}\\ 
>  \dot{x_2} 
> \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
>  x_2\\ 
>  -rx_2+x_2\cos(x_1)-\sin(x_1) 
> \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
>  0\\ 
>  1 
> \end{pmatrix}u$
>
> Now: $H(x_1,x_2)=P(x_1)+K(x_2)$ where $P$ is the potential energy and $K$ is the kinetic energy.

What are the next steps to get to the full storage function? And how do I know if it is dissipative?

Thanks!!